# Malformed UTF-8 character error in regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

I have 'Malformed UTF-8 character' error when I'm putting some scalar data in XML::Simple or Data::Dumper. There are regular expressions on the lines where the error occurs.

```
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at /usr/share/perl5/XML/Simple.pm line 1690.
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Data/Dumper.pm line 682.
```

At the moment I failed to reproduce the error with a small piece of code.

```
XML::Simple 2.18
Data::Dumper 2.124
perl v5.10.1
```

Comment: What do you mean by an invalid UTF-8 character? Do you mean invalid code points, invalid UTF-8 byte sequences or something else? Can you give some examples of the "invalid UTF-8 characters" that you wish to remove?

Comment: It is a UTF-8 string, which may occasionally contain some binary data. I'm not in command of how it's being built.

Comment: any byte that starts with 0 is valid UTF-8, but at the same time can be what you call "binary data"

Comment: The source of the evil is "Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at /usr/share/perl5/XML/Simple.pm line 1690". I want to get rid of this error. XML::Simple is 2.18

Comment: So your real problem looks as if you would like to create an XML document and get an error about invalid UTF-8 characters? Note that XML doesn't allow all valid UTF-8 characters to be embedded. These characters (most control characters below U+0020) need to be embedded in CDATA sections or stripped from the input data.

Comment: @0xA3 Yes, I want to make an XML. But the following works without errors. `perl -MXML::Simple -le '$str .= chr for 0 .. 31; print XMLout({ body => [ $str ] })'` I'm embarassed.

Comment: Does "I'm embarassed" mean your problem is solved?

Comment: Downvote for *unclear* question - problem cannot be reproduced. When you edit your question to provide a small hexdump of the faulty data, I'll undo my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arose because somewhere deep in the code of the application there was `Encode::_utf8_on` with a scalar, that wasn't a proper UTF-8 string.

Comment: I know, now it sounds quite stupid. I'm not sure if I should delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try piping your data through [Encoding::FixLatin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encoding-FixLatin/).  If the 'binary' bytes you're encountering are actually Latin-1 characters then they'll get converted to valid UTF8.  If they really are random binary bytes then they should at least get converted to random (but valid) UTF8 characters :-)

Comment: Perhaps they should, but XML::Simple 2.18 doesn't like them :) Latin-1 characters are not enough unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The core Encode module provides facilities for [Handling Malformed Data](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#Handling-Malformed-Data). I never used them myself, though.

Comment: > Some encodings ignore CHECK argument. For example, Encode::Unicode ignores CHECK and it always croaks on error.
:S